# django: must be a User Instance when trying to save, but it is!

Tags: django, django-models

Im sure this is probably a simple answer, but I cannot see anything wrong with this!

Im just trying to save a record, and its saying `Cannot assign "<User: jason.kinnear>": "Confirmation.user" must be a "User" instance.`

This is the code:

```
u = User.objects.get(pk=18)    
cr = Confirmation(details='...', user=u).save()
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Model Definition for Confirmation

```
class Confirmation(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    details = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have tried both

```
user = models.ForeignKey('User')
```

and

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Im not too sure of the difference to be honest

EDIT 2:
The User class has been extended like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as BaseUser
class User(BaseUser):
    """Extra user information"""    
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', null=True, blank=True)
    defaults = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you show us your model definitions?

Comment: Are they both the same `User`?

Comment: Do you mean is 18 Jason.Kinnear? Yeah it is the same user

Comment: No, not the same user. The same `User`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, thats that I mean. User 18 is User jason.kinnear

Comment: Except that's not what I mean.

Comment: ok...im not quite sure what you mean then. Thanks for your patience though :)

Comment: The code provided works for me. If its causing a ValueError, then are you overriding the User class? Also, providing details as for your Django and python versions is always advisable.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice Sidharth. I have edited the question with how I have extended the User class.

Comment: It's sounding more and more like they're not the same `User`.

Comment: Thanks for your interest Ignacio, but I still dont understand what you mean by not the same User...

Comment: Show how you import `User` in the relevant modules.

Comment: ahh ok. Thankyou Ignacio! I was importing the wrong User (as they were both called 'User'). Thanks everybody for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this question has an answer, Ignacio was correct (in the comments). The imported `User` was not the same. The Django `User` was extended with another `User` class and I was importing the wrong one. (Ignacio, if you would like to post an answer I will make that the accepted answer)