# Valueerror while running datamigration

Tags: django, django-south, data-migration

I am running datamigrations for my project. My aim is to make a user follow all his articles which were created before the activity stream was implemented

I had created the migration file using the command

```
python manage.py datamigration articles das_user_migrate_data --freeze auth --settings=maldio_project.settings.dev_keval
```

for the forward function I have the following code,

```
def forwards(self, orm):
        registry.register(orm['articles.article'])
        for articles in orm['articles.article'].objects.all():
            user = orm['auth.User'].objects.get(username=article.submitter.username)
            follow(user, article, actor_only=False)
```

I have the proper imports needed for the operation. But while running the `migrate` command I get the following error

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: User object>": "Follow.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

I have seen other questions with the same error but the solutions mentioned didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your "follow" function I'd say that the class of the User you're trying to assign to the Follow object instance is not the same as you are referencing in the FK of Follow.

Make sure you didn't subclass Django's User. See [django: must be a User Instance when trying to save, but it is!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485899/django-must-be-a-user-instance-when-trying-to-save-but-it-is)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I am not extending the `auth.User` class in my code and the `foreign key` is properly mapped to the `auth.user`

Comment: You might have taken the str representation of the User object in the 'follow' function? Could you please add the definition of the 'follow' function to your question?

Comment: the `follow` function is a part of the `django-activity-stream` which I am trying to integrate with my project

Comment: Looking at the code of django-activity-stream it sounds like it is trying to create a _new_ Follow object pointing to a _historical_ User (that's why you get "<User: User object>" instead of the common username User object representation). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542617/how-can-i-send-signals-from-within-django-migrations

Have you tried freezing the django-activity-stream Follow model as well?